# Making a graph with multiple values from an arange

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I came across with this graph and i've noticed it sums up pretty much what I want to accomplish. I'm using matplotlib until now.

[image]

Given the code below I set up some conditions and one of them is an arange. The variables names are not that important. It's just a for loop that appends the arange values to a given list.

```
n = 10000  #individuals
n_rep = 50 #number of cycles
f = 0.025  
p_array=np.arange(0.01,0.23,0.025)  

n_samples=[]
for i in range(len(p_array)):
  forest=generate_empty(n)
  p=p_array[i]
  ntrees_p, forest=evolution(forest,p,f,n_rep)
  n_trees_p.append(ntrees_p)
```

I've tried several ways of plotting but either way i get or a single line in a plot, or multiple plots with different lines.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are `generate_empty` and `evolution` ?

Comment: `generate_empty` generates a new empty forest and `evolution` trace back the dynamics of the forest given f (probability of lightning strike) and p (probability of newborns).

Its like a Celullar Automata but with a forest dynamic